# inserting into A errors because of a foreign key contraint issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

Can someone help explain this to me and resolve it?

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2adc7/9

**The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_tblMobileForms_tblForms". The conflict occurred in database "db_6_2adc7", table "dbo.tblForms", column 'fm_id'.: insert into tblMobileForms(fm_name) values ('lol')**

My schema has the ID from tblMobileForms be a foreign key to tblForms.fm_id

Comment: What are you expecting to happen? How does this query: `insert into tblMobileForms(fm_name) values ('lol')` relate to any of the items you have inserted into tblForms (test, test, test, test, test)? You have 5 ID's to choose from and no logic to help choose one. In addition, if `tblMobileForms.fm_ID` is a foreign key to `tblForms.fm_ID` then the column on `tblMobileForms` should not be an identity column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PK on the `tblMobileForms` table has the same name as the FK on the same table. Seeing the PK is an `IDENTITY` column, you can end up with non-matching values.

In my fiddle, the `tblForms` table contained IDs  in the upper 60s. Running the `INSERT` in the child table would add a record with id 1, which does not exist in the parent table.

I'd create a new row in the `tblMobileForms` table, and reference that to the parent table.

Comment: THanks for the info.  It helps.  Thats sort of what i was thinking.

Comment: does that mean that if there is no matching values between the 2 tables, it wouldnt work.  So for example for the foreign key concept, they both tables need the key to exist.  If it doesnt, then it wont work?

Comment: @Fallenreaper That's what a foreign key does, yes. It verifies that the value you add into the child table exists in the master table. 

Think of it when you have a shop. If a customer places an order, you do want the customer to exist. Otherwise, you'd not be able to know where to send the goods and bill to.

Answer (score 3):

To do what you are trying to do you cannot set up the FK on tblMobileForms as an identity. See my fiddle below for more information.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/be6f7/2

Alternatively what you could do is to have tblMobileForms have it's own separate surrogate key and have a different FK column to the tblForms table.

Comment: That just might be what i end up doing.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an `INSTEAD OF` trigger to apply a random ID to each mobile form as it is inserted:

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.tblMobileForms_Insert
    ON dbo.tblMobileForms
    INSTEAD OF INSERT

AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Inserted TABLE (fm_ID INT, fm_html_file VARBINARY(MAX), fm_name NVARCHAR(50));
    INSERT @Inserted (fm_ID, fm_html_File, fm_Name)
    SELECT  fm_ID, fm_html_File, fm_Name
    FROM    inserted;

    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @Inserted WHERE fm_ID IS NULL)
        BEGIN
            WITH NewRows AS
            (   SELECT  fm_ID, fm_html_File, fm_Name, RowNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY fm_name)
                FROM    @Inserted
                WHERE   fm_ID IS NULL
            ), AvailableIDs AS
            (   SELECT  fm_ID, RowNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY fm_ID)
                FROM    tblForms f
                WHERE   NOT EXISTS
                        (   SELECT  1
                            FROM    tblMobileForms m
                            WHERE   f.Fm_ID = m.fm_ID
                        ) 
                AND     NOT EXISTS
                        (   SELECT  1
                            FROM    inserted i
                            WHERE   f.fm_ID = i.fm_ID
                        ) 
            )
            UPDATE  NewRows
            SET     fm_ID = a.fm_ID
            FROM    NewRows n
                    INNER JOIN AvailableIDs a
                        ON a.RowNumber = n.RowNumber

            IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @Inserted WHERE fm_ID IS NULL)
                BEGIN 
                    RAISERROR ('Not enough free Form IDs to allocate an ID to the inserted rows', 16, 1);
                    RETURN;
                END
        END

        INSERT dbo.tblMobileForms (fm_ID, fm_html_File, fm_Name)
        SELECT  fm_ID, fm_html_file, fm_name
        FROM    @Inserted

END
```

When each row is inserted the trigger will check for the next available ID in tblForms and apply it sequentially to the inserted rows where `fm_id` is not specified. If there are no free ID's in `tblForms` then the trigger will throw an error so a 1 to 1 relationship is maintained (The error would be thrown anyway since tblMobileForms.fm_id is also a PK).

N.b. this requires tblForms.fm_ID to just be an int column, and not identity.